# When to use CheckBox and when Switch

Tags: android, checkbox, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

Can anyone can tell me when to use `Checkbox` and when `Switch`?

I mean, what is the real login difference between the two in the context of a `PreferenceActivity`?

For example, will you change the next section to `Checkboxes`? It's part of a set, but using a Switch here looks better.

[image]

Comment: I'd say use checkboxes for selecting multiple linked items in a list of related preferences, and switch when the item is independent from others. But that's just me. I guess in the end it comes down to what makes sense to you (and your users, of course). Good question, +1.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I actually find this to be quite an interesting question, particularly considering that one can easily emulate the functionality of a switch using a checkbox in Android.

According to the Android developers guide, a checkbox is simply a type of switch. Check the quotes below or read the full description [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/selection-controls.html).

> **Checkboxes:** Checkboxes allow the user to **select multiple options from a set**. Avoid using a single checkbox to turn an option off or on. Instead, use an on/off switch.
>
> **On/off Switches:** On/off switches toggle the state of a **single settings option**.

Comment: It's important to note that for a set of checkboxes, an additional "submit" or "save" button is required to mark the completion. Switches however are instantaneous, with immediate effect.

Comment: @AjitZero: The style guide doesn't say that, and it's not consistent with actual practice either.

Answer (score 7):

**Disclaimer** I'm not UX expert.

Besides what @KentHawkings has already [cited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21231473/264047%20cited) from Google's [design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/selection-controls.html) (checkboxes for list of non-exclusive options and switch for a single option), there is a good (IMHO) use case for checkbox for a single option - when the checkbox clearly means yes/no.

Good idea for checkbox: "Show notifications" option.

Bad idea for checkbox: "Wi-Fi" option (as in Android Settings).
You could use checkbox here if this option was titled "Wi-Fi is enabled", but quite obviously "Wi-Fi"  with "On/Off" switch is more concise.

Note that Play Market doesn't follow Google's own guidline - it uses checkboxes in its Settings all over the place.

Comment: Google Play has a really good reason to do so, It needs to be compatible and consistent throughout all Android devices back to ancient API levels (like Android 2.3). [Switches](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) and   [switch preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/SwitchPreference.html) were added in API level 14] and switch preferences are not included in the support library that works on API level 9. I've found a [third-party library for that](https://github.com/yongjhih/SwitchPreferenceCompat), haven't tried it though.

Comment: @cuddlecheek I think, there are a couple of able programmers at Google, who could weither **1.** add switches to support lib v7 or **2.** implemet switches as custom widgets inside Play app :-P

Comment: Of course they could do that, but I suppose Google Play app and Support library are developed by different teams. So I assume Google play team didn't bother to organize adding switches to support library v7 and probably didn't find it so important to implement it themselves. I would say that if they started to developing the app for API 14+, they would use switch in appropriate places.

Answer (score 4):

After following the `Settings` option in android device, my opinion for difference between checkbox and switch is that:

1. CheckBox are usually used to mark/unmark the particular setting in the service.
2. Switches are used to turnOn/turnOff the particular services.

Possibly, that is why `checkbox` are treated as subset/type of `switch` as they allow to mark/unmark an option within the service itself( not the entire service).

Answer (score 0):

CheckBox means it is a toggle and only a toggle.
Switches means it is a toggle and if you click the text area (title and summary) some more settings window should pop up.